# Spring boot reading properties from a bean

Tags: spring-boot, properties

I found an spring boot sample code in which properties are being injected directly with @Value.

The point is that those properties come from a bean which is not present actually in the code.

The annotations have this aspect:

```
@Value ("#{envPC['desktop.url']}")
private String url = "";
```

So I have a couple of questions:
1-how can I define env bean?
2-when defining the env bean, how can I modelate the correct structure for references like: desktop.url, desktop.port....

I hope the questions are clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Environment bean is implicitly defined within Spring context. Spring collects properties from multiple sources into this bean: JVM options, property files added via `@PropertySource`, etc.

Also it can be injected like any other bean:

```
@Autowired
private org.springframework.core.env.Environment environment;
```

More details can be found at https://docs.spring.io/ or in this nice article: http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that info but I never faced such situation so when I run the example I get this exception:
`Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'envPC' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?`